# Dynamic values in Contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am working on a form where user can register a company for an event and depending of the number of people the price of the registration should change.

```
<label> Name
    [text* your-name autocomplete:name] </label>

<label> Email
    [email* your-email autocomplete:email] </label>

<label> Company name
    [text* your-company autocomplete:text] </label>

<label> Number of people
    [number* number-602 min:1 "1"] </label>

[stripe currency:usd amount:[dynamic_value] "Proceed to checkout" "Pay"]
```

I use contact form 7 plugin. I want to have a dynamic value for the amount parametr (dynamic_value). For example if customer enters that number of people for the event is 2 then the amount value should be 120(1 person cost 60$), if there will be 3 people the amount should be 180 and so on. How can I do this?

Comment: This plugin will help you : https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using the advanced custom fields plugin. Have a play around and see if you can work it out if not there's plenty of documentation.